# angular ngb-carousel with card slider

Tags: angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

How to slide cards with carousal slider similar like coursera as below link

https://www.coursera.org/browse/arts-and-humanities

I am using bootstrap cards along with card-deck class

Please help me how to achieve this with below code: